# Writing a dict to an external .json file not reflecting outside of IDE

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a Python dict to a pre-existing external .json file which is empty.

```
    usersession = {
    'session_key' : key,
    'session_secret' : secret
}

j = json.dumps(usersession)

with open('usersession.json','w') as f:
    f.write(j)
    f.close()
```

When I view the usersession.json file with Finder it is not showing that the .json file has been modified. The .json file when viewed in the IDE also does not change.

However, some sort of modification did happen because when I read and print from 'usersession.json' in a subsequent runtime (commenting out the code block that initally wrote into the .json), the stored data appears.

```
file = open("usersession.json")
data = file.read()
print(data)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It sounds like it's writing to a different file than where you're expecting. Try using an absolute path, and double check what the working directory of your IDE is.

Comment: Try `import os;print(os.path.abspath('usersession.json'))` to see where it goes

Comment: Thanks! My program file was outputting the .json file into a debug configuration folder instead of the same directory it was in.